# Textbox control dont lose value on postback if viewstate is disabled

Tags: asp.net, textbox, viewstate

When we disabled the viewstate in gridview its lose value but this case not true with Textbox control why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TextBox` doesn't need `ViewState` to persist its value. It just fetches it from the `POST` request during initialization.